# Shifter requiring to press the lever fully without resistance before engaging

Tags: shimano, shifter

I have Shimano LX shifters M571 on my trekking bike (probably from 2008, but not sure). I notice that recently it starts to behave strangely: the thumb levers do not have any resistance (and do nothing), until I press them almost entirely. Then they engage, I can release them and they operate normally. This started with the front shifter, but now also happens with the rear one.

I didn't find a way to reproduce that, but it looks to me that it happens after having not used them for "some time" (it can happen during a ride as well).

What could be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen this happen on slightly older thumb shifters. What happened in my case was that the grease inside the shifter had gone stiff, so the ratchet mechanism didn't spring back promptly. I still have it on the front shifter but that doesn't get much use on that bike. When I do use it, I have to push the lever all the way, and do so slowly. Sometimes it then works a few times before sticking again.

I fixed the rear shifter by opening it up and scraping of what grease I could, then soaking it in the lightest oil I could get (WD40) to soften the grease, cleaning that off (rags followed by rinsing with denatured alcohol), and finally regreasing. It was a few years ago but I think I had to repeat the dilute/wash a couple of times - but this was done outside work without much disassembly.

You might get away with just lots of light spray oil, at least for a while.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem.